# Logging & Tracing

Tags: c#, vb.net, logging, roslyn, trace

How to add tracing and logging to analysers? As you may not know I have been experiencing a issue to that some how causes my analyser to work in the experimental instance, but not the normal instance. So I'm thinking of adding in tracing and logging, that I can examine when I run it in the normal instance.

What are your recommendations and suggestions about approaching this? 
I desktop application I could implement a top level exception handler, but with the analysers being independent "plugins" modules for Visual Studio I can see anywhere I could implement this approach.

I think I could use ETW (which would initially require admin privileges to create the event source,) but I concern that this wouldn't be available to a portable class.

I tried

```
Debug.Write
Console.Write
```

but where can I see the output in VS? If it does output text it (to me) is lost in the noise of other outputted text.

Outputting to a file in My Documents (no admin privileges) would work, but how to create the file?

**Additional**
The portable class is targeting

```
.NET Framework 4.5
Windows 8
```

Comment: Debug.Write will be written to the [immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Isn't `debug.Write` skipped in `Release` mode?

Comment: For release configuration use `Trace class`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan What `Trace Class` ? Is it available to me given the targets of the portable class?

Comment: @AdamSpeight Yes, then use `Trace` as stated by Hamlet. Output goes to same window.

Comment: No, sorry, it not supported by portable class.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://1drv.ms/1y0PFrn). `Trace` isn't available.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan That's OK.

Answer (score 0):

One normally uses Trace Listener to write the trace information to a file. There you can read the trace information without VS. A good introduction is here:
[MSDN: Tracing and Instrumenting Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6s4h68(v=vs.110).aspx)

Read there also the description about how to use Trace Listeners. You will find that you need to read quite a lot, that it is rather complicated and has several limitations. I found most irritating that it is too slow for near real time tracing and that exceptions caused by tracing problems are thrown on the trace caller's thread. That's the last thing one wants, getting an exception because of tracing. You might find other problems due to your particular needs.

For these reasons, I wrote my own tracing class, which can be used with any .NET technology. It's reliable code, I used it for years. You can find it with detailed explanations how to use it at:
[CodePlex: ACoreLib.Tracer](https://acorelib.codeplex.com/)